# What manga chapters does the Akagi anime adapt?

Tags: akagi

I just finished the *Akagi* anime. It seems safe to conclude that Akagi probably survives the match with Wachizu, but since there are two more rounds that aren't covered by the last episode of the anime, I'm wondering how they go.

As thus: which chapter of the manga does the *Akagi* anime end on? Is it safe to assume that up to that chapter, everything covered in the manga will have been more or less covered in the anime (given that in some anime adaptations, like FMA, this isn't true)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For questions like these [**Manga Updates**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=10132) is king.

> **Anime Adaption:**
>
> **Starts** at Volume 1, Chapter 1
>
> **Ends** at Volume 13, Chapter 109
>
> **Skips** Volume 6 Chapter 51 *to* Volume 7 Chapter 56

The series currently has *28 Volumes* and is still *ongoing*.

Comment: Remarkably enough, I looked at the most recent chapter I could find, and as per the answer below, the game with Washizu is still going on...